# Set of numbers with the same number of one in binary representation

Tags: binomial-distribution, set-partition

I was looking at a good notation for a set that contains numbers which has the same number of one in binary representation:
For example, $$S_1 = \{0^{n-1}1,10^{n-1}...\}$$

is there any standard notation for such sets?

Comment: What are "numbers of same set bit"? I do not understand your deifnition of $S_1$ either.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I fixed the question. I meant the same number of set bit. S1 is a set of numbers that have 1 set bit in its binary representation

Comment: What do you mean by "set bit"?

Comment: @Snochacz I assume he means that a particular bit is the same value for every bitstring in the set. $\{001, 011, 101, 111\}$ for example all have one as the LSB

Comment: I mean the same number of set bit, for example $\{101,011,110\}$, so each number have 2 set bit.

Comment: @DiamondDuck You still have not defined the phrase "set bit."

Comment: @Y.Forman A "set bit" is (probably considered as "computer scientist jargon" and) means simply that there is a $1$ in the binary representation of the number.

Comment: @DiamondDuck I think if you rephrased the part *"...number of set bit"* to *"... number of ones in their binary representation"*, then the question would be so clear that even mathematicians will understand it (scnr), and the question might be reopened (and possibly upvoted, because I think that it's not a bad question at all...)

Comment: @Marco13 sorry all for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that counts the numbers of 'ones' that are contained in the binary representation of the number, for example, based on https://oeis.org/A000120 :

$$a(0) = 0$$
$$a(2i) = a(i)$$
$$a(2i+1) = a(i) + 1$$

Then you can define the "set of numbers that have $n$ 'ones' in their binary representation" as

$$S_n = \{ i \in \mathbb{N} . a(i) = n \}$$

Comment: thank a lot. I forgot to change the title. the first half is correct.